# Canonical bijection from $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{X}$ to $^\mathbb{X}2$ for finite $\mathbb{X}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The title pretty much says it all -- for a finite set $\mathbb{X}$, is there a canonical bijection between $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{X}$ and $^\mathbb{X}2,$ where $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{X}$ is the powerset of $\mathbb{X}$ and $^\mathbb{X}2$ is the class of functions from $\mathbb{X}$ into a set with two elements?

It's well known that $|\mathcal{P}\mathbb{X}|=|^\mathbb{X}2|$, I was just wondering if there was a particularly nice way of associating subsets to functions bijectively.

Comment: Notation $2^\mathbb{X}$ should be taken instead of $^\mathbb{X}2$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Both notations are in use. I happen to prefer $2^X$ myself, but that doesn't mean we should tell people who use the other notation to change theirs.

Comment: @Henning Makholm OK. I had never encountered notation $^\mathbb{X}2$ before.  Notation $2^X$ (which must be Bourbaki's one) is, in my own (disputable) opinion preferable because it sticks to the bijection explanation with $X$-fold cartesian product $\{0,1\}^X$.

Comment: @JeanMarie: The people who write ${}^X2$ also tend to use ${}^ba$ for _cardinal exponentiation_ while reserving $a^b$ for _ordinal exponentiation_. These two operations give the same results for natural numbers, but generalize in different ways to infinities. For example, $\omega^\omega$ is a _countable_ ordinal, whereas $^{\aleph_0}\aleph_0$ is the much larger cardinality of the continuum -- even though almost everyone agrees on $\aleph_0=\omega$. (The mainstream solution is just to be explicit about whether you're talking about ordinals resp. cardinals and let the reader disambiguate).

Comment: Of course they're sworn enemies of the people who write $^ba$ for _tetration_ instead.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Thank you very much. Very interesting. I had not the cardinal/ordinal distinction in mind at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way is to assign to each $A \subseteq \mathbb{X}$ the function $f_A: \mathbb{X} \to \{0,1\}$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ iff $x \in A$, the so-called characteristic function of $A$. We can interchange $0$ and $1$ of course, but the above ways is "standard", and corresponds to a Boolean statement, we see $\{0,1\}$ as $\{\text{false}, \text{true}\}$ and $f(x)$ is the truth value of "$x \in A$". Finiteness is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

The usual canonical bijection works no matter whether $\mathbb X$ is finite or infinite (or empty):
$$ F : {}^{\mathbb X}\{0,1\} \to \mathcal P(\mathbb X) : F(g) = \{ x\in \mathbb X\mid g(x) = 1 \} $$

Comment: Much appreciated -- I believe you've given the inverse of the bijection in Henno's answer! (I accepted his because the times were identical to my checking ability and his provided an alternative interpretation, but thank you nonetheless)

Comment: @AlecRhea: Yes, it's the same correspondence. (If you're curious about times another time, you can hover your mouse pointer on the "answered so-and-so long ago" under the post, and a tooltip will give you timestamps with second precision).